# How to make a PHP variable available in all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, global-variables

I recently took a dive into wordpress, and I noticed something really unusual, When coding I noticed that a particular variable called the `$post` variable was available for me to manipulate whenever I need it, as along as my page is within the `wp-includes`, `wp-themes` or `wp-plugins` folder without me calling any external page or function.

So I started developing a site without wordpress hoping to understand the mystery behind that anomaly..

I would appreciate all help on making me understand this phenomenon. I would like to use such technique in building sites. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an anomaly. That variable is present in global *scope* and is being defined in either of the files that you have mentioned. You can easily do it like

**include.php**

```
<?php
$myGlobal="Testing";
?>
```

**anyfile.php**

```
<?php
include "include.php";
echo $myGlobal;
?>
```

And you can use it in your functions as well, as long as you refer to the global one, for example

**anotherfile.php**

```
<?php
include "include.php";
function test()
{
 global $myGlobal;
 echo $myGlobal;
}
test();
?>
```

[**Theory**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well
>
> By declaring (a variable) global within the function, all references to either variable will refer to the global version. There is no limit to the number of global variables that can be manipulated by a function.

Go through this [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) once and you will have much better idea of how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at global variables:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

and superglobal as well:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 0):

php.ini
register_globals = on

$post
$get
will be available anywhere

Comment: But that's an awful thing. Besides, I believe OP refers to `$post` as in regarding to a blog post. Not a master in WP but given how they like globals, it wouldn't surprise me

Comment: ye, this isn't a good programming. and its disabled by default in php starting from version X (can't remember)